# How to write a function returning const char*, which is a modified const char* argument?

Tags: c++, c, scope

I have to write a function (c++), which definition is:

```
const char* getFileName(const char* name);
```

to make things short, this function will take name, check some conditions and append to it a postfix, making it a proper filename. For example:

> name = "someFile", return = "someFile-hd.png"

`const char*` returned by this function will be immediately passed to another, which takes `const char*` as an argument

```
something->loadFile(getFileName("someFile"));
```

The problem I have, is that when I create a `const char*` in my function it will have a scope limited to the function it was created in. On the other hand, I can't modify the code of `loadFile` function, since It's a 3rd party library I am using.

I can write a wrapper around `loadFile` to delete the `const char*` I've created, but I would not like to do that, since this is a porting exercise and this would break some templates I've created to make it easier.

Is there a way to write this function like I've described?

Thanks

EDIT:
small explanation:

`getFileName` is a function I am trying to write, I can change the return type, but it has to fit as a parameter to `loadFile` function. My main problem is that `const char*` returned by `getFileName` is either lost because it's out of scope or I have to delete it explicitly, which breaks my porting template. I would like to generate the filename in one function call and do nothing else about it [in other words, in original code I have `loadFile("something.png")` and I want to change it to `loadFile(getFileName("something"))` without adding any new lines after that.

Comment: Does `getFileName()` have be thread-safe / reentrant? If it doesn't, you can return a pointer to a `static` buffer local to that function.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with pthreads and would rather have it thread-safe, just to be sure.

Comment: Can you change the return type of `getFileName()` ?

Comment: To clarify, is your main problem deleting the  const char* returned by getFileName?

Comment: Until when is the returned value required to be valid? That's the question you need to answer because that's the condition you need to detect and use to trigger the release of the thing returned. If forever, you can never free it. If until the next call of the function by the same thread, then you can use TSD to do it.

Comment: getFileName is a function I am trying to write, I can change the return type, but it has to fit as a parameter to loadFile function. My main problem is that const char* from getFileName is either lost because it's out of scope or I have to delete it explicitly, which breaks my porting template. I would like to generate the filename in one function call and do nothing else about it [in other words, in original code I have loadFile("something.png") and I want to change it to loadFile(getFileName("something")) without adding any new lines after that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Even if it doesn't need to be re-entrant, returning statics is a very bad idea. Consider `something->loadSeveralFiles( getFileName("someFile"), getFileName("SomeOtherFile") );`. Oops, it opened the same file twice and ignored the other. _Don't return pointers to static_, leave the allocation of this variable to the caller. Or even better, use std::string if that is an option.

Comment: @Lundin, true, there are lots of nasty side effects that can pop up from returning statics, I only thought the questioner's case was simple enough not to worry about your particular example. I guess functions like `strtok()` had too much influence on me in the past, and it shows :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can change the return type of `getFileName()` to be `std::string` you could do the following:

```
std::string getFileName(const char* a_name)
{
    std::string result(a_name);
    result += ".png";

    return result;
}

// No memory management req'd
something->loadFile(getFileName("someFile").c_str());
```

Comment: Damn :) I thought about using string but I've returned the result.c_str() instead of just returning the string and doing .c_str() afterwards! Thanks a lot! This solves it without breaking my template!

Comment: As far as I know, using `.c_str()` for this purpose is considered bad practice since you can't rely on existence of copy of `std::string result`.

Comment: @Liho, thanks but I _think_ you can as the temporary object will live until the end of the expression.

Comment: @Liho: this works and is Standard compliant, though it is brittle. The Standard explicitly guarantees that any temporary will live until the end of the full expression (ie, until reaching `;`), so the result of `getFileName` will live until `loadFile` has been executed, but no longer. On the other hand, if someone were to refactor it into two lines `char const* name = getFileName("someFile").c_str(); s->loadFile(name);` then this would have undefined behavior --> brittle, brittle...

Answer (score 2):

The main logic of using `const` arguments is that it means, that you are not going to change this argument in the body of function that takes it.

If you want to change it, don't use `const`.

And don't worry about casting `char*` to `const char*`. There is implicit conversion for this.

You don't really need to change this `const char*` argument though. You could use it to construct `std::string` object and avoid possible memory leak - check answer by [hmjd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033896/hmjd).

Comment: This is leaking memory though... as well as being slightly inefficient since `strcat` will recompute the length of the first string while `strcpy` had already (though this is the C API fault, not yours).

Comment: Well it depends how he plans to use it. If he is going to call `something->loadFile(getFileName("someFile"));` then it won't leak or will it? And for efficiency, I think it is still faster than overhead connected with construction of `std::string` and copying in solution by hjmd.

Comment: @LihO: That depends on what loadFile does. Since loadFile is a member of "something" but getFileName isn't, it is might weird to assume that loadFile will clean up memory that doesn't belong to its own class. I agree with Matthieu, this will leak memory and is therefore bad practice. Further, there is really no point in returning pointers like this in C++.

Comment: Yeah. Now I realize, that solution by hmjd is much better. Thank you guys. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Returning pointers from functions usually don't make sense in C (and even less so in C++).
Since you tagged this both C and C++, this is the C answer.

The common way to do this would be something like:

```
void getFileName (const char* name, 
                  char*       complete_name, 
                  size_t      complete_name_n)
{
  ... // create a new file name in a temp buffer

  if(the new file name has a strlen() < complete_name_n)
  {
    strcpy(complete_name, the new file name);
  }
}

// caller:
char name_buf [N];

getFileName(name, name_buf, N);
something->LoadFile(name_buf);
```

For example, the whole Windows API calls functions exactly in this way, leaving the allocation of parameters to the caller, letting the function concern itself only with its task (and not with memory allocation etc).

Though of course, this means that the caller has to type several rows instead of one. At this point you should ask yourself what's most important:

- to write clean function interfaces without obscure pointer returns nor strange, needless, leaking dynamic allocations, *or*
- to type as little code as possible in the caller to reduce keyboard and programmer wear-and-tear.